# Black screen in Firefox OS simulator

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os

When I launch Firefox OS 1.3 simulator from app manager; the simulator gets launched but its showing a black screen only.

Is there something I missed out while launching?

Note: I am using Firefox 30.

Comment: JFYI: While the simulator is an add-on, this question is not about developing add-ons, hence I removed the firefox-addon tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons to show black screen in Firefox OS Simulator. I recommend you install up-to-date version as like 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange you have tried to reinstall the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we both are facing same issue.Do you see the black screen after the "based on Mozilla Technology" splash screen?Please check below question that i posted.Also try out some of the steps suggested there.
[Firefox OS 1.3 simulator doesn't work.(runs but shows a black screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742233/firefox-os-1-3-simulator-doesnt-work-runs-but-shows-a-black-screen)

Comment: yes. I tried out those steps in your post but still no luck

Comment: @Joseph ok.so you are also getting similar black screen.can you see the home and orientation button?what about the add-on for firefox os 1.1 which has to be installed and run seperately(i mean not through the app manager),is that working?

Comment: No. Only "based on Mozilla Technology" splash screen