# Firefox OS 1.3 simulator doesn't work.(runs but shows a black screen)

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I am learning app development for firefox os.I installed a simulator for version 1.3 at my work place and it was working fine.I could write simple web app and run on the simulator.But when i installed the emulator on my home pc It was installed successfully but then was showing just a black screen.I am sure i have installed the correct version.I am using firefox 30.The simulator does show up in the app manager but when i start ,it just show a black screen.I don't understand why this is happening.I tried installing other versions like 1.4,2.0 and 2.1,but same thing happens for all the simulator addons. what could be the problem?
[image: firefox os similator running]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing the issue, but one solution may be to install again the add-on:

- Uninstall all simulators add-on you have;
- Reboot your computer (or kill the process b2g or b2g-bin);
- Install the add-on again.

It should fix the issue as you may have a process hanging.

Please tell me if it's solving the problem.

Comment: i have tried unistalling and reinstalling the add on multiple time.A reboot has also been tried but doesn't work.What is strange is that if i swipe then it shows shifting to next screen.I tried clicking on the change orientation button and it kind of detects and changes.But i can't see anything on the screen.I wonder whats wrong because i am using same version/addon at my work place.How do you kill the b2g/b2g-bin process?cant find them under processes.

Comment: I did try killing b2g-bin process as well.No luck.

Comment: Have you tried enabling verbose logging in the simulator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator#How_to_enable_verbose_logging

Comment: @JasonWeathersby you talking about debugging for apps right?My problem is that i can't see the homescreen itself.can't even see the home button.Just a black screen as shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

On IRC, @tweeper pointed out that the black screen also appears in Firefox Nightly (not just the Simulator), but that the release channel of Firefox works correctly.

This makes it sound like some kind of graphics issue on the specific machine he's using that has been broken in Gecko relatively recently.  I'd suggest filing a [Graphics bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Graphics) about this so it can be investigated further.

Comment: i was able to run nightly by opening in safe mode and then disabling hardware accelaration. However simulator still doesn't work.I have already filed a bug for this.

Comment: i would also like to add that i installed an old firefox os simulator(1.1) which can be run directly and not from app manager and That add on works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably an AMD bug (or whatever brand your graphics card is). I had the same problem with spotify and solved it by disabling hardware acceleration. Here I solved it by forcing the use of the other graphics card (If you have hot switch and running on windows (don't know for other OSes. If someone is aware of it...), you can force the b2g-bin.exe process to launch in power-saving mode and it will use the other graphics card.
Did the trick for me.
My integrated graphics is Intel HD 4000 and the other one AMD Radeon 7600m series